# is there a way to check file exists or not on server using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function check_file(urlToFile) {
  var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false);
  xhr.send();
  if (xhr.status == "404") {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

it throws an error 404 in the console when a file not found on a given URL

Comment: Client side JS has no knowledge of the server, it sends and receives data to an address. This is only possible if the server has a "Does this exist" API of some sort that you can call, which we can't answer as we don't know the server.

Comment: _“it throws an error 404 in the console when a file not found on a given URL”_ - uhuh. And? You say that, as if it constituted an actual problem?

Answer (score -1):

you can deal with the 404 error by using onerror() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onerror